# Elasticsearch removing duplicates by _delete_by_query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index `tor`. Before i have a script which did write data with many duplicates. I've corrected this issue, but old duplicates still are located in elastic. Also i have a query that detect:

```
POST tor/_search
{
 "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
     "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
       "field": "device.idx",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i delete this duplicates?

Comment: If it's one-shot operation you may prepare the list of document IDs to be deleted and use something like [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query for `_delete_by_query`.

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev I have about 65 000 000 duplicates for 5 months collecting...

Comment: In this case I think the way to go is to scroll the entire collection, get the list of document IDs to delete, and sequentially run delete requests on all 65M of them, probably using [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). Another approach would be to use that `device.idx` as document ID (here [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) might come handy) if this is of course the desired unique ID for your collection.